WebView2 IsPasswordAutosaveEnabled
I have a WPF application that embeds a WebView2 control on one of my views. I added an eventhandler:
webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += webViewCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;            

In my debugger the execution does go to my handler and it sets another property IsGeneralAutofillEnabled but it will not set the IsPasswordAutosaveEnabled.
What am I missing about setting and saving Passwords in a WebView2 control?
Here is the code I tried:
private async void InitializeWebView2()
 {
     await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
     webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += webViewCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;            
 }

 private void webViewCoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     CoreWebView2Settings Settings;
     Settings = webView.CoreWebView2.Settings;
     Settings.IsPasswordAutosaveEnabled = true;
     Settings.IsGeneralAutofillEnabled = true;
 }


this problem was with the WebView2 control. Microsoft has now fixed the problem
